# How to quantify the influence of multiple variables on a time series data

Tags: time-series, statistics, correlation

I have three variables in my time series data ($X_1,X_2,X_3$). I then calculate $y = (X_1+X_2)-X_3$ for each time $t$. Now, I need to look at a time interval and come up with a quantitative measure that tells me the influence three ($X_1,X_2,X_3$) variables on $y$. My expected outcome will be - for this time interval $t-10$ to $t$, the influence of $\Delta X_1, \Delta X_2, \Delta X_3$ on $\Delta y$ is $a$, $b$, and $c$ respectively. Using $a$, $b$, and $c$, I should be able to tell if $X_1$ or $X_2$ or $X_3$ influenced $y$ more during a particular time interval. What kind of statistical method I can use here?

Comment: why is correlation not a good measure for this linear relationship?

Comment: which is better - correlation or covariance?

Comment: if mean is zero they are equivalent

Comment: [Linear (Pearson) correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient) is normalized covariance. Correlation is nice since it has a fixed range (-1...1) which allows you to set meaningful thresholds. Covariance is nice because it will not break if one of your features has zero or very small variance. Pick one :-)

Comment: What if I am concerned only about the variables that are increasing y? I want to know which of the three X made y to go up in a time interval and by how much influence. I’m not worried about the downtrend of y.